# Angular 2 hierarchical Providers in ES5

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-5

I'm getting started using Angular 2 using ES5, and I've hit a brick wall when setting up my providers. In essence, I want to make a provider depend on HTTP. Here's how i have it set up:

```
var Provider = ng.core.Class({
    constructor: [ng.http.Http, function(http) {
       // some code here that uses HTTP
    }]
});

var Component = ng.core.Component({
    providers: [Provider, ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS]
}).Class({
    constructor: [Provider, function(provider) {
        // some code here that uses my Provider
    }]
});
```

I keep getting the following error: `No provider for t! (e -> t)`

I've omitted the rest of the boilerplate code because this is where I'm stuck. Do I have a misunderstanding about how I'm injecting my dependencies? How do I set up hierarchical dependencies in Angular 2 in ES5?

Comment: It's working fine for me http://plnkr.co/edit/4pEwDnNMUIrLw9LbrrjC?p=preview

Comment: Could you use the `angular2-all.umd.dev.js ` file? So we will be able to know what is actually the `t` provider... Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out. in the actual code I was using, i ended up having something like this: `providers: [[Provider, ng.http,HttpProviders]]` which shouldn't have been a nested array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In the actual code I was using, I ended up having something like this: `providers: [[Provider, ng.http,HttpProviders]]` which shouldn't have been a nested array